# Pass a type to a DataTable function at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I am using Entity Framework in C#. My database contains the following helper function, which basically converts an IList to a DataTable with whatever entity Type is passed at runtime:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);

    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Here is a crude of example of how I need to call this function, lots of times, because there are many combo boxes:

```
        public bool Custom_EvtManualComboInputAllowed(object combo, ICustomControlType cct, string keyPressed)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)combo;

            if (cct.Name == "IngredientDirection" &&
                (cmb.Name == "CmbIngredientDirectionText" || cmb.Name == "CmbIngredientDirectionType" || cmb.Name == "CmbProteinType"))
            {

                if (cmb.Name == "CmbIngredientDirectionText")
                {
                    _CMainController.DataAccessLayer.SetContext(typeof(IngredientDirectionText));
                    dt = Functions.ToDataTable<IngredientDirectionText>(_CMainController.DataAccessLayer.GetAll());
                }
                else if (cmb.Name == "CmbIngredientDirectionType")
                {
                    _CMainController.DataAccessLayer.SetContext(typeof(IngredientDirectionType));
                    dt = Functions.ToDataTable<IngredientDirectionType>(_CMainController.DataAccessLayer.GetAll());
                }
                else if (cmb.Name == "CmbProteinType")
                {
                    _CMainController.DataAccessLayer.SetContext(typeof(ProteinType));
                    dt = Functions.ToDataTable<ProteinType>(_CMainController.DataAccessLayer.GetAll());
                }

                //Do something with "dt"
            }

            dt = null;
            cmb = null;

            return false; 
        }
```

I always know that my entity type will be the name of the combox box without "Cmb". Is it possible to use Reflection to extract the type eg. "IngredientDirectionText" or "ProteinType" at runtime and then pass is to the DataTable function? This would greatly reduce the code.

I have searched other questions, but the answers I found seem to all show how to make a Class instance using Reflection, when I simply want to pass the underlying Type. Many thanks in advance.

UPDATED: It seems one needs to Invoke an instance of the Method. This works:

```
        public bool Custom_EvtManualComboInputAllowed(object combo, ICustomControlType cct, string keyPressed)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)combo;

            if (cct.Name == "IngredientDirection" &&
                (cmb.Name == "CmbIngredientDirectionText" || cmb.Name == "CmbIngredientDirectionType" || cmb.Name == "CmbProteinType"))
            {
            string entityName = cmb.Name.Replace("Cmb", "");
            Type type = Type.GetType(string.Format("Namespace.{0}", entityName));
            _CMainController.DataAccessLayer.SetContext(type);

            MethodInfo method = typeof(Functions).GetMethod("ToDataTable", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            dt = (DataTable)method.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, new object[] { _CMainController.DataAccessLayer.GetAll() });

                //Do something with "dt"
            }

            dt = null;
            cmb = null;

            return false; 
        }
```

Comment: Does your code works? ToDataTable accepts generic type argument, and it suppose to be the same as of list argument. But in all cases _CMainController.DataAccessLayer.GetAll() is provided. What does it return? And ToDataTable doesn't need to be created as extension method if it is called like Functions.ToDataTable. Otherwise you can just call _CMainController.DataAccessLayer.GetAll().ToDataTable().

Comment: "greatly reduce the code".. just so that it's clear, that's you actual consideration here right?  and you are considering adding the overhead and complexity of a dynamic runtime to forego writing (and maintenance to) the boilerplate code for a known set of types and their identifiers?

Comment: Kazys - the data retrieval works fine. @Brett Caswell - I have updated the question to show exactly what I am trying to do. Many thanks to you both for your comments.

Comment: what does `_CMainController.DataAccessLayer.GetAll()` return as a result at the moment? just an `object` or something enumerable, like `IList<object>`?

Comment: IList<object> (enumerable), but this is not relevant I don't think to my question. As I say, the data is not the issue, it is how to call the function. Many thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just make an overload of your ToToDataTable that is non-generic and takes a Type as a parameter? You don't seem to be actually using it generically particularly - the only times you use T are in a call to `typeof(T)` (which would be replaced by the parameter) and `T item in data` which could easily be an object since it is only used in the reflection code. Would save needing complex code to call the method by reflection...

Answer (score 0):

Solved. We have to use Reflection to Invoke the Function like so:

This line gets the entity/class name from a string

```
        string entityName = cmb.Name.Replace("Cmb", "");
```

Now we get the underlying Type using this string:

```
        Type type = Type.GetType(string.Format("<SomeNamespace>.{0}", entityName));
```

This just sets the context using the Type for Entity Framework:

```
        _CMainController.DataAccessLayer.SetContext(type);
```

Setup a MethodInfo for the Function:

```
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Functions).GetMethod("ToDataTable", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Invoke the Function (which returns a DataTable):

```
        dt = (DataTable)method.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, new object[] { _CMainController.DataAccessLayer.GetAll() });
```

Many thanks to all who commented.